# How can I use the function toupper() in this code?

Tags: c

I would like to turn what i write in upper case. But i don't know how to do it.
Here is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(){
        char buffer[50];
        int retorno, leido, c; 
        while( (leido = read(0,&buffer,sizeof buffer)) > 0){
                retorno = write(1,&buffer,leido);
        }
        printf ("valor de retorno: %d\n", retorno);
        if (retorno<0){
                return -1;
        } 
        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What's with the tag spam? This is C code. Why did you tag it `c#`, `vim`, and `terminal` (but not `c`)?

Comment: ... do you know any C? This question does not really show any research effort; it's just some program and "I don't know how to use toupper()".

Comment: it was an error, sorry.

Comment: This might help: [man toupper](https://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper)

Comment: I looked for it, but i ve only found how to use toupper() with printf(). And i cant find how to use it with write().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `toupper` every single character, e.g.

```
while( (leido = read(0,&buffer,sizeof buffer)) > 0){
   for (int i=0; i<leido; i++) {
      buffer[i] = toupper((unsigned char)buffer[i]);
   }
   retorno = write(1,&buffer,leido);
}
```

Comment: You need to cast `buffer[i]` to `unsigned char` to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: @melpomene: right, thanks.I first thought that any `char` automatically representable as `unsigned char`; yet the parameter will be first promoted to an int-type...

Answer (score 0):

You can update the buffer before write function call as below:

```
char *p = buffer;
for ( ; *p; ++p) *p = toupper(*p);
```

Make sure the buffer read is a proper string in C.